# Render html content inside textarea and allow changes also

Tags: angularjs, textarea, ngsanitize

I am using a text area and i want to display html content inside it. User can make changes to content and save it also. But i am not able to achieve it.

```
 <textarea class="msgbox" 
                        name='testimonailNew' 
                        ng-model='testimonial' 
                        required></textarea>
```

testimonial has escaped data like

```
&lt;b&gt;hello prad&quot;s&lt;/b&gt;
```

I want to show user proper text like

```
hello prad"s
```

and then allow him to change it also. I already have function to unescape the string.

```
var escapestring = function(data)
        {
            var decoded = angular.element('<p>').html(data).text();
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(decoded);
        }
```

Comment: Lets say your model is <p>test123</p> - you want 'test123' to be displayed in textarea and be editable?

Comment: yup. Thats the requirement

Comment: Can't be done in a textarea. Use an html editor or contenteditable element